# Performance testing a Python data structure decision

Tags: python

I've been at this kind of a junction a lot, and I'm never able to make a definitive sure-shot decision. So I'd like if someone could explain how to 'test' simple design decisions, as well as what would be better specifically in this case.

I need a data structure which stores 'edge IDs' and 'edge weights' corresponding to a 'category'.

I can store it in two ways:

a) (edgeid,weight) pairs for each category.

```
{
cat1: [(3,4),(5,7),(6,9)...]
cat2: [(4,1),(3,6),(7,8)...]
}
```

b) Separate Lists for weight and edgeid corresponding to each cat1, with indexes correlated.

```
{
cat1: [[3,5,6...],[4,7,9...]]
cat2: [[4,3,7...],[1,6,8...]]
}
```

**Operations:**

1. Adding an (edge,weight) pair to some category. This will involve simply appending the tuple to the `cat1` list in (a), and separate append operations on two lists inside the `cat1` megalist in (b).
2. Getting all edges corresponding to a list (!most important!)
3. Removing an edge (by value of course) and the corresponding weight.

How can I make an informed decision here? I'll be using this in `igraph` so my graphs *can* involve hundreds of millions of nodes hence the lists above can be really long which is why I'm trying to keep in mind performance here.

Apart from logical deductions or conclusions from past knowledge, how can I quickly test the performance of such small things in Python? I'd love an example here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for performance then I would recommend using numpy. Using tuples and lists is just slow and numpy can actually handle data structures. What you are looking for is something like this:

```
    import numpy as np
    myarray = np.zeros(desiredsizeandshape,dtype = [('edge',list),('weight',list)])
```

And now you will be able to fill your array based on whether it is an edge or a weight. For instance imagine I have a 5 by 5 array:

```
   myarray[0,4]['edge'] = 1
   myarray[0,4]['weight'] = 5
```

Then if you want just the array of edges you simply can type:
       myarray['edge']

and you will get an array of edge values.

Comment: and to add to jfish003's comments, you could view it as a recarray if you prefer dot notation as well
>>> myview = myarray.view(np.recarray) 
>>> myview.edge  and myview['edge'] and myarray['edge']  will allow multiple options of seeing the data